# Are electromechanical actuators used in aircraft other than the Boeing 787?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, boeing-787

Are there any large (non-experimental) civil or military aircraft that use electromechanical actuators (EMA), other than the Boeing 787?

Comment: Are you asking about the particular type of advanced fully integrated electric actuators used on the 787, or electric linear and rotary actuators in general?

Answer (score 2):

Electromechanical Actuators are used in many aircraft, and in many applications.
Applications vary from controlling doors,  trims, control surfaces, flaps and air inlets to moving your business class seat to the most comfortable position.

For quite a range of examples see the [product website](https://www.eme-in.de/linear-actuators/) of this manufacturer.

Or this [video of an aileron application](https://www.safran-electronics-defense.com/video/628)